# I need to create a template for helmet decals, need help identifying correct dimensions for template

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

[image]

I am looking to created a template for helmet decals like the above image and want to have it sized correctly before it goes to print. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to go about measuring? Thanks!

Comment: The closest I personally came to this problem was hand-painting proposed artwork on a football-shaped toy so they could do some pre-manufacturing photography. The art was provided as a rectangle, and the content was to be shrink-wrapped onto the football so my work differed somewhat. I would suggest that you get with the supplier who is going to work on these, and maybe get them to provide a single sample using a grid you provide so you can get a sense of the final deformation of the art. If its just some stickers, then that is easier to derive on your own.

Answer (score 1):

To fit art to this helmet you need to know the size and shape of the helmets surface when it is laid flat.

I can tell you 2 ways to obtain the flat dimensions:

1. contact the manufacturer or the company that decals them and ask for a decal template. (alternatively find a decal manufacturer that makes decals for many helmets and use a similar one or find the exact one on their site and copy it. This look like yours: http://schoolpride.com/Helmet-Decals/Lacrosse-Helmet-Decal-Package)
   [image]
2. Remove the helmet shell (if available) and lay it flat, cutting as little as possible. Measure the flattened shell, or scan it with a flatbed. Use the new shape dimensions as outlines for your art.

Comment: That's great! Thanks! So once I get the template, how do I get the correct measurements so I can print to scale?

Comment: Open the template in illustrator, put it in the background and lock it. Do not scale it, it should be the correct size. Use the template outlines as your own template, fill it with art. Save the file in a vector format that your decal maker prefers and send it to them. So, sorry, I misspoke above, you don't need to know the size and dimensions, you just need a shape that is the correct size and dimensions to use as a guide.